# Adjusting game score based on number of games played

Tags: android, math, logic

Within a timed multiplication-sum based game I am using the following equation to calculate the percentage of correct answers:

```
//logic for the % of answers correct
double divide = ((double) score / totalQuestions);
int percentageScore = (int) Math.round(divide * 100);
```

I would like to somehow include a weighting for the total number of correctly answered questions.  For example:

```
70/100
```

is the same percentage as

```
7/10
```

But `70/100` should be a overall higher score as they were able to answer 70 questions correct in the time-limit rather than 7.

How should I do so?

Comment: This is realy close to "get this done for me"

Comment: It genuinely isn't, If I could do it i would

Comment: I know. I just said "close" ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do this. Since no one knows how you calculate the score, you can build your own logic.

In your case you could take that percentage and multiply it with the score. And/or for each 10 points add a constant, say 2. So 50/100 would give user 2*5 (as an added score for the 50) + 50/100.

I also use a tariff, the more problems solved, the higher the score. Just some thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can accomplish this is to have a target number of questions to answer within a particular timeframe combined with a penalty for each incorrect answer.  This would look something like:

```
double score(double correct, double attempted, double time, double target_rate) {
    // Validate correct <= attempted, attempted > 0, correct >= 0, time > 0, target_rate > 0
    double penalty = Math.min(correct, PENALTY_RATE * (attempted - correct));
    return (correct - penalty) / (time * target_rate);
}
```

In this case, `time` is the amount of time the user took to answer the problems in whatever unit of time you would care to consider (e.g. number of minutes) and `target_rate` is the target number of problems you would expect the user to answer correctly without error in a single unit of that timeframe.  `PENALTY_RATE` is some constant value and could be anything you decide, maybe `0.25` for starters.  Alternatively, it could be a parameter you give the function based upon some outside criteria.

This appraoch has the advantage of being tunable based upon some metric you derive from the user's expected competency.